# docker-compose up causing "socket hang up"

Tags: python, docker, sockets, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am coding on a game/logging server, the socket of the game-server is working in the same docker-compose, however, the login server in the login container, does not allow connections (Error: socket hang up).
The weird thing is, if I do not use docker compose, IT WORKS.

1. docker pull mongo
2. docker network create mynetworktest
3. docker run -d --network=mynetworktest --name=mongo mongo
4. docker build -t login_server .
5. docker run -d --network=mynetworktest -p 8000:8000 --name=login_server login_server

This works wonderfully, the login_server container can talk to the mongodb internally and responds to my postman requests.
However, it does not respond, when using docker-compose.

```
version: '3'
services:
  mongodb:
    image: mongo
    networks:
      - mynetwork

  login-server:
    build:
      context: ./login-server/
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - '8000:8000'
    networks:
      - mynetwork
    depends_on:
      - mongodb

networks:
  mynetwork:
    driver: bridge
```

Using this should work, because it implements the same logic as the code above I suppose. I am lost now, but obviously having a nice solution with docker-compose up would be waaaaay greater than doing it manually.

All the other posts I have seen, say that I should use 0.0.0.0 on the app.run(..) element. I tried everything regarding that.

Please enlighten me about the difference of the docker-compose and the manual steps. Cheers in advance and much love